# Add style to part of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I add style to part of text from an `<input>` value or a `<span>`?

I have some data like:

```
{text text} an other text...
```

And I will apply style for the text between `{}`.

My data is:  `<span>{RFS.KIS.ZWO} JJD000090085077412015021014193191</span>`

Comment: Only if the part of the text you want is wrapped in an element

Comment: This is what the `<span>..</span>` tag is ideal for. Is it not possible to add tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `SPAN`:

```js
$(function() {
    var text = $("span").text();
    var replaced = text.replace(/\{(.*)\}/, function( $0, $1 ) {

        return "{<span style='color: red;'>".concat($1, "</span>}");

    });
    $("span").html(replaced);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Text: {something}</span>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works very good for SPAN but for Input it is complicated. !!

Comment: Yes. You cannot style parts of input, but if you decide to use `contenteditable` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp or IFrame with `designmode` http://jsfiddle.net/zarjay/G3SjX/ you can apply styles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see the js part here.

If I understood correctly you want CSS styles on a part of text. To do this you can put that text in an html tag and add a CSS class with the desired style to it. (changed formatting)

e.g.
HTML

```
<span class="myStyle">text text </span> more text.
```

CSS

```
.myStyle {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: My data is : <span>{RFS.KIS.ZWO}JJD000090085077412015021014193191</span> the text is from the database.

Comment: This clarifies your question. So you can't modify the html manually. The suggested JS snippet in the other answer seems to do the trick if you want to style the text in curly brackets.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your text into tags instead of "{" "}"
calsses:

```
<span class="mytag">text text</span> text text
```

not you can style your class seperatly

```
<style>
.mytag {
   color: blue;
}
</style>
```

or tags for example (not working for all browsers):

```
<mytag>text text</mytag> text text
```

not you can style your tag seperatly

```
<style>
mytag {
   color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Older IE browsers won't automatically recognize the new tag, and it's a bad habit to keep creating new tags out of the blue. Other developers won't know what it means, for a start. There's no reason not to use `<span class="myclass">...</span>` instead.